# How can I connect my React Native application to MySQL database using JavaEE eclipse?

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, react-native

I am super new to React Native and want to use MySQL database to display data on my mobile application. This I have created a web service on JAVAEE Eclipse to connect to the database and perform CRUD operations. I am not aware of how to use the JAVA webservice as a funtion method to perform the desirable task on a button interaction. I will not be using web scripting like php and would definitely like to stay away from firebase and meteor types. It's a strict learning curve which I want to achieve without using different technology at the moment.

My development stack is React Native + JAVA + MySQL

Comment: I would recommend you to learn framework such as Spring Boot for creating RESTful web services.

Answer (score 0):

No you'll not need to use or create any java function for this.

Use `fetch` or `axios` to call your services.

Let say your service is running on localhost and on port 2000,

now make sure your 1.server and 2.android phone in which you are running RN app are in the same network.

let say you have one service which returns a list of data.

now in react-native use

`fetch("your machine/server's ip address + :port/serviceRouter or other things")`

e.g.

`fetch("http://192.168.0.2:2000/getData")`

This will work the same as a postman.

You can find official docs for other details of fetch [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network)

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about it whether this is the desired step or not. But if it works, I will come back and verify the answer. Thank you for your valuable time.